# Free personal finance software

Tags: linux, software-rec

I'm looking for a Linux replacement for Quicken - but I really don't need all the bells and whistles. Effectively what I'm looking must be able to:

- handle multiple accounts (savings, checking, credit card)
- show me how much money I have
- download transactions directly (I believe this is done through OFX)

To my knowledge, there are three programs that fit this bill. First is gnucash, but it's incredibly ugly, and also has a lot of gnome dependencies. Then there's moneydance, which seems to be nice but costs $40 and I have so far been unable to get the OFX working with my bank accounts. Finally, there's KMyMoney, which I haven't tried out yet, but from the name and screenshots, seems like it'd have to pull in half of KDE3.

Does anyone have a package they particularly like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried any of the online money managers?

[Quicken Online](http://quicken.intuit.com/personal-finance-software/free-online-money-management.jsp)

It's free and slimmed down vs. the desktop client.  It peers with most major banking insitutions and allows for automated updates.  I think of it as an online aggregator for all the online banking websites.

Downside is that Intuit hosts your information online.

[Mint.com](http://mint.com)

In a lot of ways Mint.com is the motivation for QuickenOnline. so much so that Intuit ended up buying them out recently.

<strike>[Wesabe](http://www.wesabe.com/)</strike><sup>1</sup>

[Yodlee](http://www.yodlee.com/)

These last 2 I'm not familiar with.

[Blog Entry](http://www.alexyoder.net/blog/?p=41)
[ArsTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2008/10/hands-on-mint-com-vs-quicken-online.ars)

Comparisons of the different products.  The pro is that I can access these from any place I would usually use my online banking with a uniform interface regardless of which platform I'm doing my work on, as long as I have an internet connection or cell phone reception.

<sup>1</sup> Wesabe discontinued their support for financial tools as of July 31, 2010

Comment: I gave mint.com a try but I'm really not comfortable giving some website all of my online banking account information... it just feels like a problem waiting to happen

Comment: Also it seems like nobody's managed to get it to work with a paypal plus credit card. Still, I might look into this more, thanks

Comment: I'll add this to the thread since it is an online (kind of program).  [SQL Ledger](http://www.sql-ledger.org/).  You can install it on your own webserver, so you don't have to share it with the world.

Answer (score 2):

Try [KMyMoney](http://kmymoney2.sourceforge.net/index-home.html). I've been using this effectively for 2 years now. Sadly my e-bank doesn't support OFX.
There's [OFX Plugins for KMM](http://kmymoney2.sourceforge.net/online-manual/details.impexp.ofx.html).

Comment: Sadly, KMyMoney requires KDE3 dependencies :-\

Answer (score 1):

There is also [HomeBank](http://homebank.free.fr/index.php?id=2), which includes the following features you need, amongst others:

- QIF file format import and export
- OFX file format import
- multi-accounts

It depends on GTK+, but not Gnome.

Comment: Will HomeBank allow me to update my transactions for my accounts from within the program?

Comment: I just looked into it: while HomeBank supports OFX file inputs, it requires that you download them from your bank first and then import it: it cannot retrieve your transactions itself